# CodeIgniter: Appropriate place to put reusable functions with database calls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter but want to perform best practices from the start.  I have a simple authorization call that needs to be able to be called from several controllers.  Hence I'm thinking it should be placed in either a library or a helper function.  The call would take the user's id and a required authorization "level", grab their information from the DB, make sure they have that level of access, and return true or false.

Let's say:
auth($user,5)

My first instinct is to make this a library, but it seems odd to place it directly in a library because there are DB calls, which I would think should go in a model.  It appears that only the Session library contains calls directly to the DB (for when database session storing is turned on).

So, I could access the DB directly within the library, or try to link to an external Model.  Looking it up on the web, I'm only finding people who have trouble with both routes.  Before I dive too deeply into getting one of them to work, I'd appreciate any opinions out there on how to go about this.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: One suggestion is make a base controller and base model ,all new controllers and models should inherit your base C/M and put your reusable functions in it

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that is a model function.  At least put it there until later in development.

If you later find there is a need for multiple models which would require duplicating the function, then would be a good time to move it to a helper or library.